# Creating custom (user defined) constraints in mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, constraints, customization

I have a `table` with say 5 `columns` and one among those is an `integer` type.

What I want is to create a `constraint` (a condition), that the column value should not be greater than 75 and once a value is set then, for every updation the new value should be greater than or equal to previous value.

Is it possible? I haven't seen any links related to `mysql` but I found this link related to `Hibernate` [Hibernate Validator - Creating custom constraints–Example](http://emrpms.blogspot.com/2012/08/hibernate-validator-creating-custom.html). I'm working on it, but I want to know that anything can be done like this from the `database side`.